# How to display the desired value in the ListView from the array list?

Tags: android, listview

I have an arrayList of music albums and I want to display in the ListView only the Album Name.
Could anyone give me a point about what I'm missing here? With the current code, it displays "com.example.MyClass@424fcc18"
PS: I'm using singleton to create the album.

```
ArrayList values = Manager.getInstance().getMusicAlbum();
final ArrayAdapter<Album> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Album>(this,     
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

Comment: Display something *useful* from the `MyClass` or create a `toString()` to override Object's default implementation.

Comment: I overwritten the toString method in order to return the album name but it has the same result